# ReplayKit sharing video to facebook has no commentary

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, replaykit

I'm recording a video with commentary, and I'm using replaykit. Everything is working fine on iPhone, but when I share to facebook, my videos has no sound at all. I've downloaded a video to my mac and it's m4v with sound. But when I'm trying to share it from my mac to facebook it doesn't has sound too. On youtube it works very good. Not sure is there any way I can fix it? Can I record a screen and commentary without replaykit and pass app review?

Start:

```
    RPScreenRecorder.shared().isMicrophoneEnabled = true
    RPScreenRecorder.shared().startRecording { (error) in
        if error == nil {
            //TODO: show RECORDING view
            print("start recording")
        }
    }
```

Stop:

```
    RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopRecording { (previewViewController, error) in

        if let previewVC = previewViewController, error == nil {
            previewVC.previewControllerDelegate = self
            self.present(previewVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can confirm that it's not your code.  Uploading videos to Facebook from the previewViewController works, but they have no audio.  I've also had trouble uploading to YouTube on certain devices; for example, the code works on my iPhone, but fails without any notification on my iPad Pro.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I tried opening the recording with iMovie on my iPhone, and there was no audio there either. If you're having this issue, please file a Radar (bug report) with Apple. They will fix it faster if they get more reports.

Comment: Sure right now I fixed it by recording video and audio separately and then merge two files, all of the recording is done without replay kit

Comment: I'm still looking for solution (Using RPScreenRecorder) @bgolson

Comment: @Ofir Me too, I hope they fix it in iOS 11.

Comment: @bgolson I'm using IOS 11 Beta, still having this issue. should we wait for official release?

Comment: @Ofir, no, file a bug report here: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: I wrote my own screen recorder and record audio at the same time then merge.

Comment: @Salsores, any direction create also own screen recorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be Fixed by Apple

(on the latest **IOS 11 Beta's update**)

Answer (score 1):

[Ofir Malachi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1111879/ofir-malachi) I will write it as an answer, I used some parts of [Spitfire](https://github.com/seanmcneil/Spitfire) library, I'm doing a screenshot of this part of the screen I want to "record" every 0.1 second. I'm merging those images to a video. In the same time I'm recording audio. At the end I've got "output.mov" and "recording.m4a". I'm using `AVAssetExportSession` to merge it asynchronously to the mp4 file.